# Why didn't Jiraiya use reverse summoning as a way to escape?

Tags: naruto

We know that animals can reverse summon humans who have a contract with them. So, my question is: why didn't Fukasaku reverse summon Jiraiya to Mount Myoboku while fighting Pain? If Jiraiya had enough time to write on Fukasaku's back then a reverse summon could be performed easily in that time. This would end up giving Jiraiya intel on pain and leaving the Sannin alive.

Why was reverse summoning not used to save Jiraiya? Are there any limitations on the technique that prevent its usage?

Comment: Related Question: [Why did Jiraiya have to die?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8193/why-did-jiraiya-have-to-die?rq=1)

Comment: Nope, dude. See chap 382 p 17. As you see, Jiraiya woke up and wrote the secret code on Fukasaku. If there was enough time to write that code in before Pain's final attack, I'm pretty sure Fukasaku would've had enough time to teleport back home and reverse teleport Jiraiya to Mt. Myoboku.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) in chapter 382 we also see Jiraiya has already died at p3 in chapter 382 p 16 Gamakichi even says "Did he force himself back to life with willpower?" even pain says that his heart had stopped. So even if he managed to get away before the final attack, Jiraiya would have been dead already. There for he used his final life force to write the message instead of making a futile escape attempt. Besides that you can beter post this as comment then a answer once you reach enough reputation :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply said he could have, and Fukasaku even recommended Jiraiya to do this. But Jiraiya decided not to since he already got too close to find out Pain's ability and identity. Also there would be no second chance in finding out his ability after this anymore, because Pain would be more careful afterwards.

> When Jiraiya originally summoned the elder toad couple they also asked him why he was fighting<sup>1</sup>. A few chapters after, when Jiraiya already got gravely wounded<sup>2</sup> and orders the elder couple to retreats he gives his reasoning for staying

[image]

<sup>1</sup>(chap 376 pag 3-5)
<sup>2</sup>(chap 381 pag 10-11)